# Why does logger only generate file but no output using yaml configuration

Tags: python, logging, yaml

I am setting up logger for my python app using Yaml.

While the actual configuration is done in `app/__init__.py`, the config information is read from `logging.yaml`

[image]

`__init__.py`

```
import os
import logging.config
import yaml

config_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), 'logging.yaml')
if os.path.exists(config_path):
    with open(config_path, 'rt') as f:
        config = yaml.safe_load(f.read())
    logging.config.dictConfig(config)
else:
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

# Log that the logger was configured
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.info('Completed configuring logger()!')
```

logging.yaml

```
version: 1
disable_existing_loggers: False

formatters:
    standard:
        format: "%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s"

handlers:
    console:
        class: logging.StreamHandler
        level: DEBUG
        formatter: standard
        stream: ext://sys.stdout

    info_file_handler:
        class: logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler
        level: INFO
        formatter: standard
        filename: aae.log
        maxBytes: 10485760 # 10MB
        backupCount: 20
        encoding: utf8

    error_file_handler:
        class: logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler
        level: ERROR
        formatter: standard
        filename: aae.log
        maxBytes: 10485760 # 10MB
        backupCount: 20
        encoding: utf8

    debug_file_handler:
        class: logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler
        level: DEBUG
        formatter: standard
        filename: aae.log
        maxBytes: 10485760 # 10MB
        backupCount: 20
        encoding: utf8


    warn_file_handler:
        class: logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler
        level: WARN
        formatter: standard
        filename: aae.log
        maxBytes: 10485760 # 10MB
        backupCount: 20
        encoding: utf8

loggers:

    app.run:
        level: DEBUG
        handlers: [info_file_handler, error_file_handler, debug_file_handler]
        propagate: no
```

All levels are supposed to logged to file `aae.log`. When I run the application `run.py`, I do see `aae.log` generated. However the file is empty. Nothing gets output to this file. Not even "Completed configuring logger()!" in `__init__.py`

Why is it not printing out to the log file?

Comment: Why you have 3 different file handlers all going to the same filename?  That's bananas

Comment: @wim I didn't want to have too many log files. Tried to have separate files for each. Still the same. Files generated but all empty

Comment: My point is debug handler will also include levels above (info, warn, err) so you don't need others too.  Probably, they are interfering with  each other.

Comment: multiple handlers is usually for different destinations, e.g. stderr, syslog, file.